# jacoco code coverage and aspectJ weaving

Tags: gradle, aspectj, jacoco

I am using the gradle to build in my current project. I have Jacoco for code coverage and aspectJ used for logging. Right now I am facing the issue where aspectJ weaved code affecting the code coverage.

It is 100% when we dont weave the code but it goes down badly to 70% when we use aspectJ. Any pointers??

Answer (score 0):

https://confluence.atlassian.com/clover/gradle-clover-plugin-317950477.html is a clover plugin that does compile time instrumentation. If you are open to moving to Open Clover, this should help.

They also have a aspectj-clover-plugin that instruments aspectj generated code as well.